# how to solve "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beautifulsoup4'"?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm work in Python Idle.

I installed BeautifulSoup4 with "pip install beautifulsoup4" in Powershell, and it works in Powershell's python.

But when I run in Python Idle

```
# Read Library
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

error message said

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/umts1202/Desktop/ML/bs-test1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I have no idea what to do. Please help me :(

Comment: did you test `pip3 install beautifulsoup4`?

Comment: You are missing the module `beatifulsoup4` module. see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html for an explanation of the error.

See https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html for details on how to install modules.

Comment: it looks like you have more than one python installation and in the second case you use the wrong one (i.e. not the one where the package is installed).

Comment: It doesn't change anything, but it works fine. maybe, there was two python in my work desk. Thanks for you guys. please be careful for Covid19.

Comment: (That was the first comment on Stack Overflow about Covid)